# Python:can I assume that conditions are tested from left to right and stop when met?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I will use the followig code as reference for my question:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> if a or b:
...     print(a)
...
10
>>> if False and b:
...     print(a)
...
>>> if a and b:
...     print(a)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

I will conditionally test cases where:

- `a` is defined and `b` may or may not be defined
- `a` is False and `b` is not defined, **or** `a` is `True` and `b` is defined

I would use `if a or b:` for the first case and `if a and b:` for the second one. Per my tests above it works, but this assumes that *i)* the parsing of the condition is from left to right and *ii)* it stops when the condition status is known

Is this a documented behavior of Python and are these correct assumptions?

Comment: I think you proved that yourselves. :)

Comment: Yes. Those are correct. You proved it yourself!

Comment: the problem is that it works in 2.7.3, I do not know if this is a documented design of the language (updated the question to make it clear)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

It's in the doc so it's true.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: I think, there is no other choice but to do that).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes!

All conditions are evaluated left to right.

And in most cases it will short circuit whenever a "True" condition is met, depending on what you are looking for.

For instance, in the case of `AND` both sides must be evaluated as True. But in the case of `OR` If the first side is true, it will short-circuit.

For more information about `AND` and `OR` in Python, check out [The Peculiar Nature of AND and OR](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html)

Comment: In case of `and` it will short-circuit as soon as a `False` is found.